# Vue.js Typescript Corrupted

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

After the 'npm install -g vue' (v2.6.10) step & removing strict-ssl in config file, I am consistently getting a typescript@^3.4.5 is corrupted. (See text below.) I have replicated this on more than one VM. N.B. My Node.js is v12.13.1. Is there a workaround?

> C:\Workspace\software\VueJsProjects\v2.x>npm install -g @vue/cli npm
>   WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and
>   not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade
>   your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3. npm WARN
>   deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade
>   to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching
>   binaries from AWS, smaller package size npm WARN tarball tarball data
>   for typescript@^3.4.5
>   (sha512-Mcr/Qk7hXqFBXMN7p7Lusj1ktCBydylfQM/FZCk5glCNQJrCUKPkMHdo9R0MTFWsC/4kPFvDS0fDPvukfCkFsw==)
>   seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time. npm WARN tar ENOENT: no
>   such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\WShurtleff\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\indent-string-18731e3b\package.json'
>   npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
It was solved by retrying after running `npm cache verify` as hinted in this  [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156288/error-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-tarballhttps)

For the record: 
[Official documentation for npm-cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache)

Comment: I tried this 'npm cache verify'. The command executes fine, but it doesn't fix the problem.